# Unable to replicate login and authorise process via CURL commands

Tags: api, http, authentication, curl, oauth-2.0

I am trying to implement OAuth via a series of CURL commands but I am having trouble with the Authorise step. I have captured the Authorize process in Fiddler so I know what to replicate and I have defined the process to get the access code as follows:

1. POST login credentials to the login page in order to get the
   '.ASPXAUTH' cookie in the response.
2. GET the authorisation page by sending the '.ASPAUTH' cookie and in the response get the '__RequestVerificationToken' from the
   response cookies and also the form token (also named
   __RequestVerificationToken) from the body of the webpage.
3. POST to the authorisation page by sending both the '.ASPAUTH' and
   '__RequestVerificationToken' cookies as well as the form token
   in the body.

Here are the requests I am using for each step with the username and passwords replaced:

```
curl -x 127.0.0.1:8866 -k -c cookie.txt 'https://oauth.sandbox.trainingpeaks.com/Account/LogOn?ReturnUrl=%2fOAuth%2fAuthorize%3fresponse_type%3dcode%26client_id%3dclientId%26scope%3dcoach%253Aathletes%2520workouts%253Aread%26redirect_uri%3dhttps%253A%252F%252Ftest_url.com%252Fcallback&response_type=code&client_id=clientId&scope=workouts%3Aread%20athlete%3Aprofile&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Ftest_url.com%2Fcallback' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:86.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/86.0' -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5' --compressed -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -H 'Origin: https://oauth.sandbox.trainingpeaks.com' -H 'DNT: 1' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Referer: https://oauth.sandbox.trainingpeaks.com/Account/LogOn?ReturnUrl=%2fOAuth%2fAuthorize%3fresponse_type%3dcode%26client_id%3dclientId%26scope%3dcoach%253Aathletes%2520workouts%253Aread%26redirect_uri%3dhttps%253A%252F%252Ftest_url.com%252Fcallback&response_type=code&client_id=clientId&scope=workouts%3Aread%20athlete%3Aprofile&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Ftest_url.com%2Fcallback' -H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1' --data-raw 'UserName=MY_USER_NAME&Password=MY_PASSWORD'
```

This returns the '.ASPXAUTH' cookie used in the next request.

```
curl -x 127.0.0.1:8866 -k -c cookie.txt 'https://oauth.sandbox.trainingpeaks.com/OAuth/Authorize?response_type=code&client_id=clientId&scope=coach%3Aathletes%20workouts%3Aread&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Ftest_url.com%2Fcallback' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:86.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/86.0' -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5' --compressed -H 'Referer: https://oauth.sandbox.trainingpeaks.com/Account/LogOn?ReturnUrl=%2fOAuth%2fAuthorize%3fresponse_type%3dcode%26client_id%3dclientId%26scope%3dcoach%253Aathletes%2520workouts%253Aread%26redirect_uri%3dhttps%253A%252F%252Ftest_url.com%252Fcallback&response_type=code&client_id=clientId&scope=workouts%3Aread%20athlete%3Aprofile&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Ftest_url.com%2Fcallback' -H 'DNT: 1' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Cookie: .ASPXAUTH=37D88F4FF97A59398A7F3A01AEDC4ABB32FF99FCE85B346271D9F62D9CEA65B9BF0027A0304DC1E87CDE46948A9F72CC57B1479A37CB1B54F33B74E03C4D20AC44D333FE6FFAD3A4CB69336A14DCA2C46CCBD822C569C1F231383541C99D9F6715D813D1' -H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1'
```

This returns the '__RequestVerificationToken' cookie and I get the form token (__RequestVerificationToken that is sent as part of the body) from the body of the response.

```
curl -x 127.0.0.1:8866 -k 'https://oauth.sandbox.trainingpeaks.com/OAuth/AuthorizeResponse' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:86.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/86.0' -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5' --compressed -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -H 'Origin: https://oauth.sandbox.trainingpeaks.com' -H 'DNT: 1' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Referer: https://oauth.sandbox.trainingpeaks.com/OAuth/Authorize?response_type=code&client_id=clientId&scope=coach%3Aathletes%20workouts%3Aread&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Ftest_url.com%2Fcallback' -H 'Cookie: .ASPXAUTH=37D88F4FF97A59398A7F3A01AEDC4ABB32FF99FCE85B346271D9F62D9CEA65B9BF0027A0304DC1E87CDE46948A9F72CC57B1479A37CB1B54F33B74E03C4D20AC44D333FE6FFAD3A4CB69336A14DCA2C46CCBD822C569C1F231383541C99D9F6715D813D1; __RequestVerificationToken=-_UjTRMCw6tv0jVe9bcA_JV7onmEAZZOPyx89_tZavaQY4U2Q4aAwgEx9Ghhp3i8Uh31FL-zHVFrSTAgqUgDPxpMDQg1' -H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1' --data-raw '__RequestVerificationToken=O1mxbFlJ6T3AxL1ua4Vtemuhj5lzaCIxKOm49v_NdlCkitIpfUG4DSBwPwI7jb9o4BnLDA0s3R4w3i2Ftcqph0EAifWSreOQmXYcQ1YM1JlOgFzW0&IsApproved=true&client_id=clientId&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Ftest_url.com%2Fcallback&state=&scope=coach%3Aathletes+workouts%3Aread&response_type=code'
```

This should redirect to the test URL with the access code as it does when these steps are done in the browser but instead I receive:

```
<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="/Account/LogOn?ReturnUrl=%2fOAuth%2fAuthorizeResponse">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>
```

This seems to indicate that the session has become invalidated and requires starting the process again.

I have compared the requests generated by CURL and those from the browser in Fiddler and I cannot determine a difference.

Here are the [API docs](https://github.com/TrainingPeaks/PartnersAPI/wiki/OAuth), I am trying to implement the 'Authorise' process which results in an access code. Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is tricky to automate logins via CURL, since OAuth redirects tend to involve these actions:

- Following HTTP redirects automatically
- Auto posting forms with authentication results
- Some complex messages, some of which may vary depending on the authentication method

For an easier way of testing - have a look at [OAuth Tools](https://oauth.tools), which is kind of like 'Postman for OAuth', and works with any standards based provider - here is an [introductory video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kr0SECFMoU4).